# US Income Tax: Continuing Education Deduction for New Job

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income-tax-refund, education

I started a new job as a manager in September 2021. This was my first management job. In October 2021 I spent $52,000 on a continuing education course (executive education) focused on leadership. The new course absolutely helped me onboard my new role.

I've been reading about potential deductions in the US income tax for this kind of expense. It sounds like it would be eligible for a Schedule A (itemized) deduction, but when browsing my tax preparation software it says I am actually not eligible.

I have searched multiple online resources but they don't provide details on how to claim this deduction. How can I find out specific information on eligibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what do you think you're eligible for deduction?

#### Unreimbursed employee expenses

This one goes to schedule A, but.... First you need to show that it was **required**, which it doesn't sound like it was ("*ordinary and necessary*" requirement). Then you need to show that you're a *qualified* employee. See [here](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/heres-who-qualifies-for-the-employee-business-expense-deduction):

> - Armed Forces reservists
> - Qualified performing artists
> - Fee-basis state or local government officials
> - Employees with impairment-related work expenses
>
> No other type of employee is eligible to claim a deduction for unreimbursed employee expenses.

You may have seen older (pre-TCJA) articles that describe a Schedule A deduction for unreimbursed expenses, but that has been eliminated in TCJA.

#### Education Expense Credits

Some education expenses may qualify for credits, but it doesn't sound like your case is relevant. If you want to learn more - start [here](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/qualified-ed-expenses).

Comment: Regarding the 1st half of your answer: YES, some of the resources I found were from 2016 (therefore pre-TCJA). I am looking more into it. Regarding the education credits: the page mentions some very generic conditions to be able to claim them. I wasn't able to find specific criteria that would disqualify me for such credits.

Comment: @MisterStrickland did you get 1098-T?

Comment: The university said the program is not a degree-granting program so they don't issue a 1098-T for it

Comment: So it's not eligible.